# Datepicker input not passing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm working with bootstrap and simple_form. I've adjusted in my application.js file to have a datepicker instead of the default dropdowns for simple_form date types, but when I submit, i keep getting empty string errors even after populating the field.

[image: Screenshot]

Has anyone come across anything like this before?

I appreciate suggestions as frankly I'm at a loss here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that adding the option of

```
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
```

to datepicker did the trick!